# Mac Android Studio error when typing code

Tags: android, android-studio, spell-checking

I don't know how to explain this error when, I using Android Studio on Mac. When I typing something, and click the pointer to another (ex: Another line in this video). The text automatically moves to the cursor position -> I don't want to it happen.

Please see the video with link below, and help me fix it. Thank so much!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ft1WNfJtdvw

Version 2.1.2
[image]

Comment: What is the version that you are using?

Comment: Can you provide us with your Android Studio version? And this usually occurs when you highlight something and drag and drop it, so make sure you don't have a bad mouse.

Comment: Hi, my Android Studio version 2.1.2